# Cast a smallint to boolean with slick, scala

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick

I would like to represent a postgres smallint as a boolean. I am getting error ERROR: operator does not exist: smallint = boolean, when using the asColumnOf operation. Is there a way to cast a smallint to boolean using slick.

```
case class Bike(id: Long, hasBasket: Boolean)

trait BikeTable {
class Bikes(tag: Tag) extends Table[Bike](tag, "bike") {
  def id = column[Long]("id")
  def hasBasket = column[Boolean]("has_basket")
  overide def *  = (id,hasBasket) <> ((Bike.apply _).tupled, Bike.unapply)
}

protected val bycles = TableQuery[Bikes]
}


def getBycycleFilterDetails(bycleSearch:BycleSearch): 
Future[Seq[BycleDetails]] = {
val query = for {
  bikes <- byclces

} yield (byclces.id, byclces.hasBasket)


val possiblyFilteredByHasBasket = if (bycleSearch.hasBasket.isDefined) {
  query.withFilter(u => u._2.asColumnOf[Boolean] === bycleSearch.hasBasket.get)
} else query

val result = possiblyFilteredByHasBasket.result
```

if I use

```
   u => u._2.asColumnOf[Boolean] == bycleSearch.hasBasket.get or  u => u._2 == bycleSearch.hasBasket.get
```

I get empty resultset, 
If I use

```
   u => u._2.asColumnOf[Boolean] === bycleSearch.hasBasket.get  or u => u._2 === bycleSearch.hasBasket.get
```

I get the postgres error above.The table is postgres database represents the has_basket by a smallint type which I do not have control over.

Comment: Just use boolean directly?

Comment: Not sure I understand you but I have added more code to explain the results I am getting, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you should override * method in your table:

```
trait BikeTable {
class Bikes(tag: Tag) extends Table[Bike](tag, "bike") {
  def id = column[Long]("id")
  def hasBasket = column[Boolean]("has_basket")

  override def * = (id, hasBasket).mapTo[Bike]
}
```

From Slick's [documentation](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/1.0.1/lifted-embedding.html#tables):

> Every table requires a * method contatining a default projection. This
> describes what you get back when you return rows (in the form of a
> table object) from a query. Slick’s * projection does not have to
> match the one in the database. You can add new columns (e.g. with
> computed values) or omit some columns as you like. The non-lifted type
> corresponding to the * projection is given as a type parameter to
> Table. For simple, non-mapped tables, this will be a single column
> type or a tuple of column types.

You don't need to use asColumnOf

Comment: no, I'm still getting similar results, I've updated code sample above to include the update

Comment: Also you shouldn't use "==", it compares two objects. Use methods from ColumnExtensionMethods, i.e. "===". And what is an error you've got? What will you get when use `u => u._2 === bycleSearch.hasBasket.get`?

Comment: when using u => u._2 === bycleSearch.hasBasket.get  I get the error ERROR: operator does not exist: smallint = boolean, thanks

Comment: Is that important to use smallint? Why not just define the field as boolean in database table?

Comment: I don't have control over database schema. I plan on trying to use MappedColumnType, I'll let you know how I get on

Comment: Ok. Something like `implicit val hasBacketColumnType: BaseColumnType[Boolean] =
      MappedColumnType.base[Boolean, Short](b => if (b) 1 else 0, _ != 0)` would help you

Comment: correct me if I am wrong but I dont think that this is supported, https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/1111. It is mapping results but I am unable to filter  using the type

Comment: I made small research. In latest version of Slick (3.2.3) field has_next somehow converts to Boolean without any custom implicit converters. But with Slick of version 2.1.0 it doesn't work and I get an error "Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type smallint".  If you are still interesting, this is [my repo](https://github.com/Duelist256/slick_postgres_example).
Main for version 2.1.0 and Main2 for 3.2.3. And don't forget to change version in build.sbt.

Comment: I think you should migrate to a new version, but if it is impossible, you should try doing an explicit cast using plain sql query.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think that this is supported,see github.com/slick/slick/issues/1111

A workaround that I used

```
    case class Bool(value: Boolean)
```

and

```
    implicit val hasBasketColumnType: BaseColumnType[Bool] = MappedColumnType.base[Bool, Short]({ b => if (b == Bool(true)) 1 else 0}, { i => if (i == 1) Bool(true)  else Bool(false) })
```

and use this type everywhere instead of Boolean

```
     u => u._2 === Bool(bycleSearch.hasBasket.get)
```

Dont know if this is correct way of doing it,